# How to keep a server processing running on a Google Cloud VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, virtual-machine

This question seems very basic, but I wasn't able to quickly find an answer at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance. I'm running a [MicroMDM](https://micromdm.io/) server on a Google Cloud VM by connecting to is using SSH (from the VM instances page in the Google Cloud Console) and then running the command

```
> sudo micromdm serve
```

However, I notice that when I shut down my laptop, the server also stops, which is actually why I wanted to run the server in a VM in the first place.

What would be the recommended way to keep the server running? Should I use [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or perhaps run the process as a Docker container?

Comment: Systemd is prominently mentioned at the link in your question https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/wiki/Using-MicroMDM-with-systemdsystemd  Arguably that becomes a system administration question, not truly a programming one, or at least it's in the territory in between.

Comment: When you logout, processes started at the shell are usually sent a SIGHUP to terminate them.  What about using "nohup" to start your application?

Comment: As the [Using MicroMDM with systemd documentation](https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/wiki/Using-MicroMDM-with-systemd), it suggested to use systemd command to run  MicroMDM service on linux. First, on our linux host, we create the micromdm.service file, then we move it to the location  ‘/etc/systemd/system/micromdm.service’ . We can start the service. In this way, it will keep the service running, or restart service after the service fails or server restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Using MicroMDM with systemd documentation](https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/wiki/Using-MicroMDM-with-systemd), it suggested to use systemd command to run  MicroMDM service on linux.First, on our linux host, we create the micromdm.service file, then we move it to the location  ‘/etc/systemd/system/micromdm.service’ . We can start the service. In this way, it will keep the service running, or restart service after the service fails or server restart.

Answer (score 5):

When you run the service from the command line, you "attach" it to your shell process, when you terminate your ssh session, your job gets terminated also.

To make a process run in background, simply append the & at the end of the command, in your case:

```
sudo micromdm serve &
```

This way your server is alive even after you quit your session.
I also suggest you to add that line in the instance startup script, if you want that server to always be up, so that you don't have to run the command by hand each time :)

More on Compute Engine startup scripts [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Comment: Howdy @Pievis .... I'm not sure that is enough.  Don't we also have to trap SIGHUP with nohup?